# What's the difference between OptionSelector and ItemSelector?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

When writing an app for Ubuntu, it seems I can interchangeably use the [ItemSelector](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.ListItems.ItemSelector/) or [OptionSelector](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.OptionSelector) components.

In which situation should I use each one of those? What's their main difference that grants for two separate components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having a chat with designers and SDK developers, it seems that the plan moving forward is to deprecate OptionSelector, and in general embedding UbuntuShapes in controls.

I understand that there is no particular reason for having both components, as they have overlapping functionality. So the recommendation is to use ItemSelector for now.

Comment: Let us not forget the ValueSelector, the first of these components to be deprecated.  Apparently redesigning these elements is a lot of fun.

Comment: Indeed, I had tried ValueSelector too, but didn't add it here, as it's already got a deprecation notice on the docs.